# Compare ranges of numbers SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a problem in SymPy. I solved an inequality, and I need to check if the solution is a certain range.

For example, if I wanted to solve the inequality `sympy.solve(x**3 > 0)`, (which would return `(0 < x) & (x < oo)`), and I wanted to return true if the solve function returned `(0 > x) & (x > -oo)`, it would return false, as those two ranges are not equal.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Univariate relationships can be converted to Sets and you can check for Set intersections. If the intersection not equivalent to either of the sets then neither is contained in the other:

```
>>> a, b = (0 < x) & (x < oo), (0 > x) & (x > -oo)
>>> sa = a.as_set(); sb = b.as_set()
>>> sa
Interval.open(0, oo)
>>> sa.intersection(sb)
EmptySet
```

Since there is no intersection at all, these sets must be different.

Here is a case where there is overlap (containment):

```
>>> Interval(1, 3).intersection(sa)
Interval(1, 3)
```